# Optimal design of electrical grid

Tags: power-engineering, optimization

After all that has been learned about electricity - if the grid and removing financial considerations and adoption feasibility. Imagine you're constructing for Mars or some post apocalyptic environment where sufficient technology exists to adopt a perfectly optimized solution - it needs only to be identified.

I appreciate the input and I am interested in the entire grid from production through distribution to commercial and consumer consumption. If you have additional input as it pertains to devices on battery power, I'm interested in that as well.

As far as removing

Comment: Homes here (in the UK) don't use 120Hz, 60Hz - this is an international site. We don't do "what if"  questions because (a) its never going to happen and (b) at best the answers would simply be opinions. Vote to close.

Comment: @JImDearden, in places with a centralized grid, of course it won't happen. But what about microgrids?

Comment: Obviously we would be using 240V/50Hz

Comment: @JImDearden where does 120Hz come into this? the OP is talking about 120V@60Hz.

Comment: Its the standard for supply in USA

Comment: The most common residential service in the US, Canada and a few other places is 120/240V@60Hz - 120V for ordinary wall outlets and 240V for cooking, water heating, laundry drying, air conditioning etc. Most of the rest of the world is 240V@50Hz for all residential use. Not much regret has been voiced about those choices except that it would have been a little more convenient if they had been the same.

Comment: I think OP's Q was an interesting one. Perhaps if it were phrased differently, it could still be used here. For example: "*What issues have arisen with the current convention that were unforeseen during the decision to use 120V @60Hz?*" While many things are partially opinion based, there must be some clear-cut items here. There are some clear-cut reasons why the metric system is taught over imperial, and not just because "It's the convention".

Comment: @Charles Cowie: You are wrong with 240 V@50 Hz, 230 V is more common than 240 V, but 220 V still exists too. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country